# My code won't run?

Tags: android, media-player, fragment

I am working with Fragments however this code wont run. can someone help me with this. The problem in the code seems to be with this part "(start.this,".

```
public class frag extends FragmentActivity {
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(start.this, R.raw.praise1);
            mp.start();
            }else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }   }


    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the start in `start.this`?

Comment: what does your code do ?

Comment: it starts and stop music , im trying to put it in a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
public class frag extends FragmentActivity {
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp == null) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.praise1);//==> Here is the change
        mp.start();
        }else {
            mp.stop();
            mp = null;
        }   }


});
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `start.this` to an actual context.  You could use `getParent()` or you could store the context before creating the `onClickListener` and pass it in:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final Context context = this;

//inside the onClickListener
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.praise1);
```